# How to parse form-data from Stream in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, wcf

I have a webservice that will accept stream (Image). I was able to successfully save the image but part of it is I also need to get the form-data that is part of the Stream.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? Or any suggestion perhaps to achieve same functionality.

Best regards,

Comment: What do you mean by form data? How can the stream contain something else than the image itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could stream it as an object or structure.

```
struct WCFStream 
{
   Image myImage;
   String formString1;
   String formString2;
}
```

You should provide a DataContract in which you serialize a structure similar to the above and send it, then deserialize it on the target machine, check this example out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx